# see what ARC does?

Tags: objective-c

If I understand correctly, all ARC does is automatically add memory-management statements such as `retain` and `autorelease` in the proper places in a program. Is there any way to see all the memory-management statements that ARC automatically adds to a program?

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode's assistant editor, choose to view the Assembly for the file you're working on. You should see calls to functions like `objc_retain` and similar; these are the functions inserted by the compiler to support ARC.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CFGetRetainCount to see the retain count:

```
CFGetRetainCount( (__bridge void*) object );
```